Error in execute .exe file OSError: could not get source code (win10-64x)
I want to convert my python file to exe with pyinstaller that containing following code:

from ravendb import DocumentStore

URLS = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
DB_NAME = "sa"
store = DocumentStore(urls=URLS, database=DB_NAME)
store.initialize()
class Foo(object):
   def __init__(self, name, key = None):
       self.name = name
       self.key = key

class FooBar(object):
    def __init__(self, name, foo):
        self.name = name
        self.foo = foo

with store.open_session() as session:
    foo = Foo("PyRyDB")
    session.store(foo)
    session.save_changes()


when I convert it (with pyinstaller, cx_Freeze or Auto PY to EXE) in terminal task completed successfully
but when I run .exe ,it generate following errors(just when I used ravendb package in my code):
OSError: could not get source code
[2212] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception
How can I fix it?
